# Alarm without Service

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to schedule alarms without having to use a `Service`, I just want to schedule them from my application when starting it.

I have this code in my `Application`:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            10 * 1000,
            10 * 1000, alarmIntent);
}
```

and this is my `Alarm` class:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarm!");
    }
}
```

I also added `<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"></receiver>` to the Manifest, but the alarm is never triggered. Am I missing something, or do I have to use a `Service` ?

**Update**: I moved the code from the `Application` to the main `Activity`. Still, no alarm.

Comment: you can check this document for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Are you certain your `Application` code is running? Do you have the `<receiver>` in the right spot in the manifest? You have your Receiver running in a separate process. Do you have a filter on your logcat that's omitting that log print?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I put a breakpoint both on setting the alarm and receiving it in the `Alarm` class. The `<receiver>` in the Manifest is in the `<manifest>` tag.

Comment: Well, on Android 5.1+, you cannot use `AlarmManager` for polling periods under one minute. I am seriously hoping that trying to do work every 10 seconds is merely for temporary testing. Beyond that, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see if your alarm is scheduled. Note that the "inexact" nature of `setInexactRepeating()` means that the `dumpsys` time for your alarm will not be accurate.

Comment: The `<receiver>` needs to be inside the `<application>` tags. Plus, what CommonsWare said, but I'd think it should fire at least once, pretty quick.

Comment: @MikeM. I moved it into the `<application>` tag, still nothing

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, the 10 seconds is only for testing

Comment: @CommonsWare changed the ten seconds into 90 and it seems to work now. Any source on that? The docs still have a 5 second example.

Comment: That's interesting. I only [tested `setRepeating()`, and for 5.1 at least they rounded up to one minute](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/03/23/alarmmanager-regression-android-5p1.html). AFAIK, this behavior is still undocumented.

Comment: @CommonsWare The alarm fires also when set to 10secs, and indeed it seems like rounded up to 1 minute.